# Undefined method `collection' for #<Mongo::Client> Did you mean? collections (NoMethodError). Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, automated-tests

I am working with automated test. This is the first time I'm working with mongoDB.

So, I am trying to create a generic method to find a document in a desired collection that will be passed as parameter. I've found some examples and all of them use the `.collection` method. It doesn't seem to work in my project.

Here's my DB client code:

```
require 'mongo'
require 'singleton'

class DBClient
include Singleton
  def initialize
    @db_connection = Mongo::Client.new($env['database']['feature']['url'])
  end

  def find(collection, value)
    coll = @db_connection.collection(collection)
    coll.find(owner: 'value')
  end
end
```

And here's how I instance my method

```
DBClient.instance.find('collectionTest', 'Jhon')
```

When I run my test I get the following message:

```
undefined method `collection' for #<Mongo::Client: cluster=localhost:>
  Did you mean?  collections (NoMethodError)
```

The gem I'm using is mongo (2.6.1).

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/ruby/current/Mongo/Client.html), there is indeed no method collection in Mongo::Client. What you are looking for is the [[] method](https://api.mongodb.com/ruby/current/Mongo/Client.html#[]-instance_method). The code will then look like this:

```
require 'mongo'
require 'singleton'

class DBClient
  include Singleton

  def initialize
    @db_connection = Mongo::Client.new($env['database']['feature']['url'])
  end

  def find(collection, value)
    coll = @db_connection[collection]
    coll.find(owner: value)
  end
end
```

EDIT: I've also changed the line with the find itself. In your original code, it would find documents where owner is 'value' string. I presume you want the documents where owner matches the value send to the function.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot @václav! I really appreciate your help. The weirdest thing is that I've found `.collection` method in [Mongo API documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/ruby/1.7.0/file.TUTORIAL.html).

Comment: @GabrielaVital that is the documentation for mongo 1.7.0 and it looks like a lot of the api has changed, e.g. in the example there is Mongo::Connection which doesn't exist in newer apis. The readme with tuorials and whatnot can be found [here](http://api.mongodb.com/ruby/2.6.1/index.html) - notice the 2.6.1 in the url.

Comment: Got it! I'll take a look at it. Thanks again! =)